# Evitar que usuário seja logado duas vezes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autenticação

Em meu projeto, tenho um módulo de login que funciona perfeitamente. Até ai tranquilo, mas da forma que está não consigo barrar o mesmo usuário logado duas vezes. Ou seja, eu consigo logar com o mesmo usuário duas vezes, e não é isso que quero. Porque posso ter problemas com isso.

Como que eu posso fazer pra barrar essa operação ? Digo, fazer uma verificação no ato do login na minha aplicação e se por acaso o usuário estiver logado na aplicação, barrar essa nova tentativa enquanto o mesmo usuário estiver logado em minha aplicação ?

O código do meu login:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
{
    //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
    Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();
    if (login != null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login, false);
        Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //pagina padrao para todos os usuarios...
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Coloque propriedades no usuário que controle se ele está logado ou não

```
public class Usuario 
{
    ...
    public bool Logado { get; set; }
    pubic string SessionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UltimoLogin { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

## 2. Implemente um `ActionFilter` que verifique se há uma sessão já aberta

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Filters 
{
    public class UniqueSessionActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var contexto = new MeuProjetoContext();
            // Recupero a Id do Usuário logado aqui.
            // Não sei como você está fazendo, então inventei um método
            var idDoUsuario = RecuperarIdDoUsuarioLogado();

            var usuario = contexto.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == idDoUsuario && u.Logado && u.SessionId != filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID);

            if (usuario != null) {
                // Se o último login foi feito dentro do período de um dia
                if (usuario.UltimoLogin.AddDays(1) > DateTime.Now) {
                    // Usuário logado em outro lugar.
                    usuario.Logado = false;
                    contexto.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    contexto.SaveChanges();
                    // Destrua aqui a Session do Usuário se houver uma.
                } else {
                    // O login do Usuário expirou.
                    var controller = (MeuControllerBase) filterContext.Controller;
                    filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
                }
            }

            this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Só que `RedirectToAction` é `protected` no `Controller`. Você terá que fazer um `Controller` base reintroduzindo `RedirectToAction` pra usá-lo dentro do `ActionFilter`:

```
public class MeuControllerBase: Controller 
{
    public new RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string action, string controller)
    {
        return base.RedirectToAction(action, controller);
    }
}
```

## 3. Na criação do Ticket de Autenticação, preencha `Logado`, `SessionId` e `UltimoLogin`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
{
    //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
    Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();
    if (login != null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login, false);
        Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);

        login.Logado = true;
        login.UltimoLogin = DateTime.Now;
        login.SessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;

        db.Entry(login).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //pagina padrao para todos os usuarios...
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Por favor não usem comentários para discussões longas. Os comentários de vocês foram [movidos para uma sala de bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19096/discussion-on-answer-by-cigano-morrison-mendez-evitar-que-usuario-seja-logado-du).