# NullReferenceException em Filtro de Usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autenticação, filtro

Em meu projeto fiz um filtro pra ver se o usuário já está logado. Para evitar que o mesmo logue duas vezes no sistema.

De acordo com [a resposta dessa minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42366/evitar-que-usu%C3%A1rio-seja-logado-duas-vezes/42400#42400) eu faço uma classe de filtro e busco o *ID* do usuário na sessão e faço toda a verificação no banco de dados.

O que acontece é que estou tendo um erro de referencia nula e não sei direito o porque. Estou passando o *ID* do usuário na sessão, mas não estou conseguindo capturar ele na hora de fazer essa verificação, me gerando esse erro:

> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

E o erro está sendo gerado nessa linha:

```
var idDoUsuario = (long) filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UsuarioID"];
```

A nível de maior informação, vou colocar os códigos da classe que uso de filtro e da *action* que uso pra fazer a autenticação.

## Filtro

```
 void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var contexto = new EntidadesContexto();
        // Recupero a Id do Usuário logado aqui.
        // Não sei como você está fazendo, então inventei um método
        var idDoUsuario = (long) filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UsuarioID"];           

        var usuario = contexto.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UsuarioID == idDoUsuario && u.Logado && u.SessionID != filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID);

        if (usuario != null)
        {
            // Se o último login foi feito dentro do período de um dia
            if (usuario.UltimoLogin.AddDays(1) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                // Usuário logado em outro lugar.
                usuario.Logado = false;
                contexto.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                contexto.SaveChanges();
                // Destrua aqui a Session do Usuário se houver uma.                    
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
                // O login do Usuário expirou.
                var controller = (MeuControllerBase)filterContext.Controller;                    
                filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("Index", "Autenticacao");                   
            }
        }
```

## Autenticação

```
 [FiltroSessao]
    [HttpPost]       
    public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
    {
        //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
        Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();
        if (login != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Nome.ToString(), false);
            Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);
            Session.Add("UsuarioID", login.UsuarioID);

            login.Logado = true;
            login.UltimoLogin = DateTime.Now;
            login.SessionID = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;

            db.Entry(login).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //pagina padrao para todos os usuarios...
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Só pra destacar, eu passo o *ID* do usuário nesta linha:

```
Session.Add("UsuarioID", login.UsuarioID);
```

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Você tentou colocar um breakpoint na linha que a variável é chamada pra ver o que tem dentro do dicionário dinâmico `Session`?

Comment: Ainda não. Mas creio que não irá me retorna nada no intellitrace. :(. Porque é estranho ele não capturar o *ID*, sendo que ele já está na sessão. Mas vou ver aqui e te falo.

Comment: Colocando o breakpoint me retorna isso: *filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UsuarioID"] = null* e *idUsuario = 0*. No mais, ele consegue capturar o login e a senha, menos o *ID*. :(

Comment: Bom, ou há problema em como você está definindo a Session, ou ela não funciona dentro do filtro por algum motivo. Vou ter que pesquisar isso pra você.

Comment: Entendi. Mas só explicando: Eu jogo o *ID* do usuário na sessão pra usar em um link que redireciona pra página de detalhes daquele específico usuário. Então creio eu, que o problema seja porque a *session* não tá funcionando dentro do filtro. =(.

Comment: Utilizar o Filtro `[Authorize]` não resolveria para você? Se o problema é o tempo, 1 dia por exemplo, isso você pode definir no `web.config`

Comment: @RichardDias não porque eu preciso que não deixe o usuário logar duas vezes. Ou seja, enquanto o usuário x estiver logado, não ter como ele logar. Não em um dia, mas sim não deixar enquanto tiver logado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei, e pelo que vi do seu código, `[FiltroSessao]` está executando antes de você definir o valor da `Session`. Há duas maneiras de resolver:

- Mudar de:

  ```
  void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  ```

  Para:

  ```
  void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  ```
- Fazer `FiltroSessao` receber parâmetros:

  ```
  namespace SeuProjeto.Filters 
  {
      public class UniqueSessionActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
      {
          public long UsuarioId { get; set; }

          void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
          {
              var contexto = new EntidadesContexto();
              // Recupero a Id do Usuário logado aqui.
              var idDoUsuario = UsuarioId;     

              var usuario = contexto.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UsuarioID == idDoUsuario && u.Logado && u.SessionID != filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID);

              if (usuario != null)
              {
                  // Se o último login foi feito dentro do período de um dia
                  if (usuario.UltimoLogin.AddDays(1) > DateTime.Now)
                  {
                      // Usuário logado em outro lugar.
                      usuario.Logado = false;
                      contexto.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                      contexto.SaveChanges();
                      // Destrua aqui a Session do Usuário se houver uma.                    
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
                      // O login do Usuário expirou.
                      var controller = (MeuControllerBase)filterContext.Controller;                    
                      filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("Index", "Autenticacao");                   
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Uso:

  ```
  public class ControllerExemplo 
  {

      public long ExemploUsuarioId { get; set; }

      public ControllerExemplo() {
          ExemploUsuarioId = HttpContext.Current.Session["UsuarioID"]);
      }

      [FiltroSessao(UsuarioId = ExemploUsuarioId)]
      public ActionResult Index() { ... }
  }
  ```

Comment: Essa linha: *var idDoUsuario = UsuarioId;*, seria a que eu tenho certo ? Assim: *var idDoUsuario = (long) filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UsuarioID"];* ?

Comment: Veja que eu alterei pro Filter aceitar um parâmetro externo, então você não usa a Session dentro do Filter.

Comment: *PassePorAquiOIdDoUsuario* seria então: *HttpContext.Session["UsuarioID"];* ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Isso.

Comment: Ué, o *HttpContext* ta dando erro: 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get"'. Erro de sobrecarga ? Ta assim:         
*[FiltroSessao(UsuarioId = HttpContext.Session["UsuarioID"])]*.

Comment: Defina uma variável na construção do *Controller* que receba o `UsuarioId`. Melhor que usar o `HttpContext` diretamente no atributo.

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo na pergunta ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Feito.

Comment: Boa. Mas só uma coisa: esse *Current* não pega de jeito nenhum, daí to tirando ele. Funciona também né ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago É pra funcionar sim.

Comment: Cara, tem alguma coisa errada. Não funciona. Da o mesmo erro de antes:  'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property'...

Comment: Esse erro só sai quando eu declaro *static*: *public static long UsuarioID { get; set; }*. Isso ta errado né ?

Comment: Não, pode ficar assim mesmo.

Comment: Com o *static* ? Mas mesmo assim da erro. =(. Esse aqui: *An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type*

Comment: E se faço a primeira opção da isso: *'IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface*

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi no seu código, você mantém uma session com o ID do `User` apenas pra recuperar no `filter`. Não seria possível recuperar o `User` a partir do `UserName`? Dessa forma você não precisaria manipular uma Session.

Você consegue o userName do user logado acessando `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`. Caso precisar testar se o User está logado é possível checar o valor de `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`;

```
void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var contexto = new EntidadesContexto();

        var userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;           

        // estou assumindo que seu objeto Usuario possui a property UserName
        var usuario = contexto.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Logado && u.SessionID != filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID);

        if (usuario != null)
        {
            // Se o último login foi feito dentro do período de um dia
            if (usuario.UltimoLogin.AddDays(1) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                // Usuário logado em outro lugar.
                usuario.Logado = false;
                contexto.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                contexto.SaveChanges();
                // Destrua aqui a Session do Usuário se houver uma.                    
            }
            else
            {
                // O login do Usuário expirou.
                var controller = (MeuControllerBase)filterContext.Controller;                    
                filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("Index", "Autenticacao");                   
            }
        }
```

Comment: Boa solução. Vou testar e se funcionar ou não, eu aviso aqui !